# Filtering a model's child inside a form partial view in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I'm using Rails 3.2.13 and Active Admin 0.5.1 and using a form partial on the form. On the model's form partial page, I have a table of all the model's (has many) children (using a arb partial page with table_for) and I want to filter all the children based on certain criteria. So basically Book has many pages and I want to filter the page's attributes. I've googled everything I can about filters and looked at the source code but I can't figure out how you use filters when not on the index page and for a child element instead of the parent. When I try to use filter on my partial I get:

```
undefined method `filter' for #<Arbre::Context:0x007fdab572a078>
```

Basically I want to use index page of the model's child with the table and filtering in a form partial. Does anyone have any idea how to get filtering on the view to work?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it looks like you're putting the filter call where it's generating an HTML view. It should go outside of that.

The filter itself should be constructed using MetaSearch syntax. Something like :pages_title_contains should do it.